# Posting a form data from a xamarin forms app to a restful webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, restful-url

I created a restful webapi and decided to use the microsoft account/register option to register new users.
I tested this very well using Postman with the option x-www-form-urlencoded in the body section using a post.
This works great and writes to the database without any problem.

I went further to write the code below in my xamarin forms app

```
public class RegisterService
{
    public async Task<bool> Register(RegisterBindingModel objReg){

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Constants.lnregister);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objReg);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

        using(Stream stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            stream.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
        }

        try{
            await request.GetResponseAsync();
            return true;

        }catch(Exception ex){
            string errormessage = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }

    }
```

All I got back was the error below

```
    {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00052] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.12.0.20/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1029 
      at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.12.0.20/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:550 
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.12.0.20/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.12.0.20/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.12.0.20/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.12.0.20/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.12.0.20/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
      at Articles.ArticlesServices.RegisterService+<Register>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00164] in /Users/xxxxxx/Projects/Articles/Articles/ArticlesServices/RegisterService.cs:28 }
```

My uri looks like this http://xxxx.com/Api/Account/Register

I am new to all these. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your API is expecting POST data in url encoded format - you need to set `ContentType` as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: I tried it and still didn't work

Comment: Like I said this works well using Postman. Can it be that I have to enable cors? Just thinking